# AWS Rekognition: Is there any API to remove or unindex face from collections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

My requirement is:

1. Register users in different departments. So I created multiple collections as per department and indexed face in collection.
2. Now I want to remove users so I also  want to remove some faces from single collection using faceId.

Is there any API present in AWS rekognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one API is available in AWS rekognition which deletes faces from a collection. You specify a collection ID and an array of face IDs to remove from the collection.
Please check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DeleteFaces.html#rekognition-DeleteFaces-request-FaceIds).